# Where can I find documentation on the openssh/sftp-server protocol?

Tags: linux, sftp, centos7, openssh

Is it possible to manually execute the command `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server` and try to write some command or text that allows me to know if it works? for example, list directories.

Where can I find documentation on the `openssh/sftp-server` protocol after ssh login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTP is a binary protocol, defined by IETF standard draft. Latest version can be found on IETF website: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13, but make sure it's what your server supports.

As it's a binary protocol, you would need a specialized client program to use it.